# Tkinter Input and Output in One Widget

Tags: python, tkinter

I've been been attempting to create my own basic Python IDE. I've created an interface which contains an input text box which allows me to enter syntax and a pmw.ScrolledText which displays the resulting output from the Python interpreter.

What I'm really hoping to do is combine these two widgets into a single widget which can handle both input and output. I haven't found any such widget but I'm fairly certain it is possible to do this somehow since Idle is written in Tk and it is basically what I'm looking for in my application. Looking through the Idle source code isn't really showing me a concise way to do this.

Basically I'm looking for a something like a pmw.ScrolledText which takes input and can also display output.

I'm just wondering if this is possible with Tk and any ideas on the potential route that could be taken to make it work.

Thanks.

Comment: What IDLE uses is basically the [Text widget](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm), one for the editor and another one for its console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's definitely possible. The text widget is what you want to use, but you'll have to do some coding to handle displaying a prompt and then performing an action when the user hits the return key.

I think the simplest thing to do is to set a mark right after inserting a prompt, and then when you detect the return key, grab everything from that mark to the end of the file as the command to be run.

Here's a brief example that illustrates the technique. It isn't perfect (for example, you can delete the prompt), but it shows the general idea.

```
import Tkinter as tk

class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.text = tk.Text(self, wrap="word", height=20)
        self.vsb = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient="vertical", command=self.text.yview)
        self.text.configure(yscrollcommand=self.vsb.set)
        self.vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y")
        self.text.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)

        self.text.bind("<Return>", self.process_input)
        self.prompt = ">>> "

        self.insert_prompt()

    def insert_prompt(self):
        # make sure the last line ends with a newline; remember that
        # tkinter guarantees a trailing newline, so we get the
        # character before this trailing newline ('end-1c' gets the
        # trailing newline, 'end-2c' gets the char before that)
        c = self.text.get("end-2c")
        if c != "\n":
            self.text.insert("end", "\n")
        self.text.insert("end", self.prompt, ("prompt",))

        # this mark lets us find the end of the prompt, and thus
        # the beggining of the user input
        self.text.mark_set("end-of-prompt", "end-1c")
        self.text.mark_gravity("end-of-prompt", "left")

    def process_input(self, event=None):
        # if there is an event, it happened before the class binding,
        # thus before the newline actually got inserted; we'll
        # do that here, then skip the class binding.
        self.text.insert("end", "\n")
        command = self.text.get("end-of-prompt", "end-1c")
        self.text.insert("end", "output of the command '%s'...!" % command)
        self.text.see("end")
        self.insert_prompt()

        # this prevents the class binding from firing, since we 
        # inserted the newline in this method
        return "break"

root = tk.Tk()
root.wm_geometry("400x100")
app = Application(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I can see how the text widget is used for input but how would output be displayed? Would I need some widget immediately above the text widget which can display output in an ascending fashion? (pmw.ScrolledText seems to only support descending)

Comment: @Matt: how would the output be displayed? You just insert it into the widget (eg: `the_text_widget.insert("end", "the output")`)

Comment: Well that was a silly question. I didn't know I could do that with the text widget. Had to write a little program just to try it out. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Wow thanks! You definitely went above and beyond here! Thanks again!